# How do I get the column names from a row returned from an adodbapi query?

Tags: python, adodbapi

Suppose I query a database like this :

```
import adodbapi
conn = adodbapi.connect(connStr)
tablename = "[salesLT].[Customer]"

cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "select * from %s" % tablename
cur.execute(sql)

result = cur.fetchall()
```

The result is, I think, a sequence of SQLrow objects.

How can I get a list or sequence of the column names returned by the query?

I think it is something like this:

```
    row = result[0]
    for k in row.keys():
        print(k)
```

...but `.keys()` is not it.

nor `.columnNames()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`cur.description` is a read-only attribute containing 7-tuples that look like:

```
(name, 
type_code, 
display_size,
internal_size, 
precision, 
scale, 
null_ok)
```

So for column names you might do:

```
col_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
```

Reference: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Answer (score 0):

There is a columnNames property on the collection of SQLrow objects.

So,

```
for k in result.columnNames:
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

q=conn.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE")
pd.DataFrame.from_records(q.fetchall(),columns=q.keys())

Comment: Can you clarify how this answers the question?  This looks like you're using Pandas (which wasn't part of the original question) and also unclear how your answer satisfies what the OP (from 8+ years ago) was looking for.